# reload an iFrame with the scrollbar set to a specific coordinate

Tags: javascript, iframe, scrollbar

I was wondering how could I reload any website using javascript and set it in a way that when it reloads the scrollbar is looking scrolled down to a certain position. I'm unsure as to how to look for this in Google honestly so I haven't digged up much =/.

I think it has to be somewhere in the instruction to reload it and so far I have:

```
document.getElementById('life').contentWindow.scroll(0,0); //doesn't work
        document.getElementById('life').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

although the first one gets me:

> Permission denied   to get
>   property Window.scroll of
>   http://www.google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website in the iframe is from a different domain than the current page, you won't be allowed to affect it at all with Javascript.  This is an intentional property of Javascript to prevent XSS.